# Sending (zip) file with Suave with the correct name

Tags: f#, suave

I have been researching creating a web server using Suave. Currently, I am trying to get it to send a zip file in a GET request. I have successfully made my application send a file, but the name of the file I receive when doing the request in Postman is "response" or "response.html", depending on which function from Suave's `Files` module I use. That said, when I manually rename the file to .zip, I can open and unzip it like a normal .zip file, which means that it is really the downloaded file's name that is the problem. The code below is what I've got now.

```
open JSON
open System
open System.Threading
open Suave
open Suave.Filters
open Suave.Operators
open Suave.Successful
open Suave.Web
open System.IO
open Suave.Writers

let sampleJsonPath = @"C:\VS Projects\Research\Sample.json"
let sampleZipPath = @"C:\VS Projects\Research\Sample.zip"
let getJson() =
    File.ReadAllText(sampleJsonPath)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
    let mimeTypes =
        defaultMimeTypesMap
            @@ (function | ".zip" -> createMimeType "compression/zip" false | _ -> None)

    let config =
        { defaultConfig with 
            mimeTypesMap = mimeTypes
            cancellationToken = cts.Token
        }

    let app = 
        choose 
            [ GET >=> choose
                [ path "/hello" >=> OK "Hello GET"
                path "/jsonString" >=> OK (getJson())
                path "/jsonFile" >=> warbler (fun _ -> getJson() |> JSON)// for only on startup: ... >=> (getJson() |> JSON)
                path "/zip" >=> Files.sendFile sampleZipPath false
                path "/goodbye" >=> OK "Goodbye GET" ]
            POST >=> choose
                [ path "/hello" >=> OK "Hello POST"
                pathScan "/content/%d" (fun param -> OK (sprintf "Found integer:\n%d" param))
                pathScan "/content/%s" (fun param -> OK (sprintf "Found content:\n%s" param))
                path "/goodbye">=> OK "Goodbye POST" ]
            RequestErrors.BAD_REQUEST "Unknown request encountered"
            ]
    let listening, server = startWebServerAsync config app

    Async.Start(server, cts.Token)
    printfn "Ready to receive requests"
    Console.ReadKey true |> ignore

    cts.Cancel()

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Googling has so far turned up nothing I could use. I have also tried many of the other functions in Suave's `Files` module instead, including `Files.browseFile sampleZipPath "Sample.zip"` (which also gives a file named "response.html") and `Files.file sampleZipPath` (which gives a file name "response"), but so far without success.

How do I supply the name of file to be sent?

Comment: Looks like this is a Postman issue; see https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2082

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filename is set with HTTP response header "Content-Disposition" and is not handled by Suave automatically:

```
   let setFileName name =
     setHeader  "Content-Disposition" (sprintf "inline; filename=\"%s\"" name)
```

So, the code will be as

```
path "/zip" >=> setFileName "Sample.zip"
            >=> Files.sendFile sampleZipPath false
```

Depending on desired behaviur you can replace `inline;` part with `attachment;` to show "Save file" dialog in browser

Comment: Using `attachment;` from the browser works (interestingly not during my first try, though). Using Postman still results in "response.html". Do you know if this is a quirk of Postman?

Comment: Okay, I just say the comment about the bug in Postman under my question.